# PHP: POST Request to ASP.NET website results in 500 server error when html tags included

Tags: php, asp.net, post

My situation: I need to send text to an ASP.NET web service using POST. The entire page there is a form:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Discussion.aspx?classroom=lG39il1cotOAGJwiNvmQlIPfwmjikD%2fAHLhjjGInAZQ%3d&amp;Page=Posts&amp;ID=794239&amp;Sort=&amp;SortOrder=" id="aspnetForm">
```

So, I figured if I sent a POST request to this form with the correct inputs it would work. And, to an extent, it has. The form inputs are as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDw..." />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWYQLrt..." />
```

And a bunch of other inputs. The code I have used is as follows:

```
// grab form info
    $inputs = extract_form_inputs($discussion['body']);
    $inputs['__EVENTTARGET']                    = 'ctl00$cphMain$ctl01$btnSubmit';
    $inputs['ctl00$cphMain$ctl01$tbNickname']   = "Your Instructor";
    $inputs['ctl00$cphMain$ctl01$reMessage']    = $message;

    // submit form
    $r = request_send($discussion['url'], $inputs);
```

extract_form_inputs does exactly that. $discussion['body'] is the content of the page. $discussion['url'] is the URL of the page. request_send has two arguments: ($url, $post_array). It performs rawurlencode on each element of the array and joins them up as keypairs, in the same way as http_build_query.

The request is url encoded properly, sent to the correct page, and works fine until I insert html tags. I have checked - the 'greater than' and 'less than' symbols ('<' and '>') are url-encoded properly. However, the server responds with a 500 error.
It accepts any other text.

Has anyone else come across this sort of problem?

Is there some setting on an ASP.NET server that denies html? I can't see this being the case - there is a rich text editor on the website that I am sending requests to. This text editor performs the same request as I am, only I am doing it remotely. The rich text editor sends html to the form - I have checked that, too, using javascript.

Note: I do not have the power to modify the ASP.NET server.

Comment: Also: The site uses RadEditor. Not sure if that makes any difference, but i hear it's popular in the ASP.NET realm.

Comment: have you tried using a headers viewer to see exactly what data is being sent?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [validateRequest](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/) flag/attribute is set and therefore your data is considered harmful and rejected.

Comment: Perhaps. I had considered something like this, but I am not experienced with ASP.NET at all.
The only contradictory is that the textbox on the website itself sends html to the same form - and is accepted.

Comment: oh, hm... I let this answer stay anyway (like a "checklist" in case some else has a similar problem).

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/1843) or [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to log the actual request your browser sends and then compare it to your script's request. Can you log *all* the data `request_send()` sends, including all headers? Depending on how `request_send()` works you might be able to route it through fiddler, too, which perhaps makes it easier to compare the requests, e.g. when I run

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('proxy'=>'tcp://localhost:8888')));
file_get_contents('http://php.net', 0, $ctx);
```

the requests shows up in fiddler (8888 being fiddler's default proxy port).

edit: Do you only receive a `500 Internal Server Error` or does the response contain more information? In case php doesn't fetch or doesn't return the response body you might want to look that up in fiddler, too.

Comment: I receive a 500 server error. The screen looks like this if I output the response: http://bit.ly/9UYCIu

I'll grab firebug and compare the requests.

Comment: Ah ok, detailed errors are unavailable, too bad (but to be expected on a "real" site ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

I have compared the results and found that the website stupidly url-encodes the messages twice before submitting. Not even full url-encoding - it misses most unwanted characters. Still, the formatting now works - I just url-encode the message twice before sending and it comes out fine on the other end.

Thanks for the help!